# i want refresh my table after close modal (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function in my component and I want to refresh the table with the next function; `this._empresaService.getAllEnterprisePaginated(1);`, this function is into my service, but in the modal service and this component is from enterprise component

CODE enterprise component

```
createEnterprise() {
        this._empresaService.createNewEnterprise(this.imagenSubir, this.enterprise_name)
        .then((resp: any) => {
            resp = JSON.parse(resp);
            if(resp.out == 1) {
                this.toastr.error('La empresa ' + this.enterprise_name + ' ya se encuentra registrada en el sistema', 'Error!', {
                    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left',
                    progressBar: true
                });
                return;
            } else {
                this.toastr.success('La empresa ' + this.enterprise_name + ' fue creada exitosamente', 'Empresa creada!', {
                    positionClass: 'toast-bottom-left',
                    progressBar: true
                });
                this.cerrarModal();
                // this._empresaService.getAllEnterprisePaginated(1);
                // for (let i = 0; i < this._empresaService.allEnterprise.length; i++) {
                //  var emp : Enterprise = this._empresaService.allEnterprise[i]

                // }
            }
        });

    }
```

CODE ENTERPIRSE MODAL SERVICE

```
getAllEnterprisePaginated(init_page: any = 1) {
        let page = {init_page: init_page}
        let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/getallenterprise';
        return this.http.post(url, page)
        .pipe(map((resp: any) => {
            this.allEnterprise = resp.recordset
            return resp;    
        }));
    }
```

i put my function but doesn't work

Comment: puedes hacer un stackbliz please ! that will be helpful

Comment: you need to subscribe to the getAllEnterprisePaginated() method, http.post method returns an observable and it's not executed until you subscribe to the method. More about http here - https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

enterprise component

```
this._empresaService.getAllEnterprisePaginated(1).subscribe(data =>{
for (let i = 0; i < data; i++) {
       var emp : Enterprise = data[i];
   }
})
```

you are not getting any value from this._empresaService.allEnterprise
     console.log(this._empresaService.allEnterprise);